# In Python how do I extract all substrings that cross a certain index in a longer string?

Tags: python, split, sliding-window

Say I have a string (mystring). I want to extract all possible substrings of mystring so long as the substrings are lengths 8-15. I've been able to do that with no problem (see code below). However, what if I want to only extract these substrings if they overlap a certain part of mystring? The overlap is defined by the position in mystring rather than a certain letter of mystring, as the letters are not unique across mystring.

In the example below, I might want my substrings to include zero-based index 11.

```
mystring = "JACKANDJILLRANUPTHEHILLFORWATER"

substrings = set()
for i in range(0, len(mystring)):
     for length in range(8,16):
         ss = mystring[i:i+length]
         if len(ss) == length:
             substrings.add(ss)
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "overlap"? Could you post a sample of your desired output?

Comment: Thanks for the questions. By overlap I just mean include that position. So, "JACKANDJ" and "JACKANDJI" are valid substrings of lengths 8 and 9, for instance, but they don't cross position 11 in mystring. But "ANDJILLR" and "ANDJILLRA" are 8 and 9 length substrings that cross (zero-based) index 11 in mystring, so they are valid based on the index I have chosen for this example. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Simple answer

You could check that `11` is included in `[i, i + length)` by checking `i <= 11 < i + length`:

```
mystring = "JACKANDJILLRANUPTHEHILLFORWATER"

substrings = set()
for i in range(0, len(mystring)):
     for length in range(8,16):
         ss = mystring[i:i+length]
         if len(ss) == length and i <= 11 < i + length:
             substrings.add(ss)
```

#### As set comprehension

You could do it like this:

```
substrings = {mystring[i:j] 
              for i in range(0, len(mystring))
              for j in range(i + 8, min(i + 16, len(mystring)))
              if i <= 11 < j}
```